# overwrite column names in pandas dataframe automatically

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to give all column names in a csv file dummy names which are integers from 0 to 400. However, the following code doesn't work, I get an error saying the syntax is wrong. What is my mistake?

`df = pd.read_csv("df.csv", sep=',',  encoding='utf-8', header=0, names = [0:400])`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can change `header=None`, add parameter `skiprows=1` and omit parameter `names`, because [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) add column names from `0` to (`length of columns - 1`) by default. Parameter `sep=','` is default, so can be omitted too.

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""a,b,c
1,5,7
2,7,8
3,1,9
4,8,6
1,5,3"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), header=None, skiprows=1, encoding='utf8')
print df
   0  1  2
0  1  5  7
1  2  7  8
2  3  1  9
3  4  8  6
4  1  5  3
```

Or change parameter `names` to `names=range(400)`, because you have `400` columns:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), header=0, names=range(3), encoding='utf8')
print df
   0  1  2
0  1  5  7
1  2  7  8
2  3  1  9
3  4  8  6
4  1  5  3
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with

```
df = pd.read_csv("df.csv", sep=',',  encoding='utf-8', header=None, skiprows = 1)
```